# App Maker delete items on table and update

Tags: javascript, import, google-app-maker

I have an app that I would like to be able to take columns from a google spreadsheet and make a list on a table in my app. Also I would like to be able to remove items from this table.

As of now I am using the AMU library function `AMU.deleteAll`, all it does is

```
AMU.deleteAll = function(widget){
  var records = widget.datasource.items;
  records.forEach(function(record){
   record._delete();
  });  
};
```

So what happens is that when I have a completely new and blank table my app can update from my spreadsheet when I use `AMU.import.fromSpreadsheet` (check here for full library goo.gl/RkeqZw) it will take all the items from my spreadsheet and place them properly in my table, after that I can use the delete function to remove all items on my table. Here is where things get all screwy, when I try to use the import function again the list gets populated with empty entries and if I try to use the delete function I get an error:

> "Drive Table internal error. Record not found. Caused by: Execution Failed. More information: Object not found at path: camo0A_084fQ. (HTTP status code: 404) Error: Drive Table internal error. Record not found. at deleteAllData (ServerScript:232)"

I am not sure why this is happening, to me it seems like the data is being saved and the delete function only removes the value, and not the actual entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete all items from your model you can make single server call (the code you quoted above does sever call for each individual item loaded on client):

```javascript
// server script to delete all records from model
function deleteAllRecordsFromModel() {
  var allRecords = app.models.MyModel.newQuery().run();
  app.deleteRecords(allRecords);
}

// client script to call server function
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function() {
     // TODO: Handle success (optional)
  })
  .withFailureHandler(function() {
     // TODO: Handle error (optional)
  })
  .deleteAllRecordsFromModel();
```